# How to sort updates based on release date on debian testing?

Tags: debian, package-management, upgrade

I'm a user of linux mint debian linux distro which is based on debian testing. Debian testing is a rolling release distro. The testing nature of this distro cause some package updates to be buggy. I'm looking for a way to sort packages by release date. I want to install updates after a mount day released to make sure there is minimum bug. I'm already familiar with a good program named apt-listbugs which show me reported bug before installing a package which help me to find reported bugs.

In short: **How I can sort updates based on release date on debian testing?**

Comment: If you run into a buggy package, you can recover an older version from [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do a donwload-only upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get --download-only dist-upgrade
```

then check the timestamps of files in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, these are not, as you can think, the timestamp of download, but the timestamps of the same .deb files on the server.

So remove the files that are too much new (with the help of `find`, i suggest), and then do a no-download upgrade, that will use the remaining files in the preceding directory:

```
sudo apt-get --no-download dist-upgrade
```

Alternatively, you can get the timestamps of upgradable packages from the `ls-lR.gz` file residing on the server, though also downloading this file amount to 6-7MB. Here is a script to get the ordered list

```
#!/bin/bash

server_list_url="http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ls-lR.gz"
server_list="${server_list_url##*/}"
LANG=en

# get urls of upgradable packages
apt-get --print-uris --yes dist-upgrade |
  awk -F \' '/(ht|f)tp/ { print $2 }' |
  sed -r 's/^.*\///' >local_list

if [[ -s local_list ]]; then

  wget -qN "$server_list_url"

  # sort older packages by time (8th fiels is year)
  zgrep -F -f local_list "$server_list" |
    awk '$8 !~ /:/' |
    sort -k8,8n -k6,6M -k7,7n -k9

  # sort newer packages by time (8th field is hour:min)
  zgrep -F -f local_list "$server_list" |
    awk '$8 ~ /:/' |
    sort -k6,6M -k7,7n -k8,8 -k9
else
  echo "No package to upgrade" >&2
fi
```

Comment: As I said before I don't want to download pckages. I just want to create a list of available updates and their release dates. then sort them based on the release date.

Comment: @user9224: I added an alternative in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but you can use **`wajig`** for a similar purpose. It's `upgrade` command creates DEB files of your currently-installed packages (it uses **`dpkg-repack`**) which are about to be upgraded. This happens before the upgrade takes place. Here's what the command looks like:

```
wajig --backup=/path/to/dir upgrade
```

The resulting packages are placed inside a directory (under "**/path/to/dir**) whose name is the current date and time.

Comment: I don't want to download pckages. I just want to create a list of available update packages and their release dates and then sort them based on the release date.